# Is there a way to avoid appending AUCTeX variables in the file when working with multiple files?

Tags: auctex

When editing multiple files, AucTeX keeps track of the master file by appending the following to each file:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "../document"
%%% End:
```

I'm editing a document with multiple colleagues and I don't want to add this to their files when editing them.

Is there a way to set an AucTeX variable pointing to the path of the master file, and whenever I hit <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, it will look for that file?

One option is to hit <kbd>M-:</kbd> and type `(setq-default TeX-master "../document")`. Is there a better way than that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what AUCTeX does when `TeX-master` is not set, nowadays, but if you use the default `latex-mode` that comes with Emacs, the corresponding `tex-master` is guessed by looking for a nearby buffer with the usual `\documentclass` thingy.  If you keep one document per directory, this is usually all it takes to DTRT and you don't need to set any file-local variable: just make sure you have that main .tex file opened in a buffer in that same Emacs session.

AUCTeX being usually fancier than this builtin `latex-mode`, I expect it also has some way to guess the right `TeX-master`.  If it doesn't, then I suggest you file a feature-request.

But there are other options:

- Set the `TeX-master` from a `.dir-locals.el` file. 
  To set up a `.dir-locals.el` file, the best way is through Emacs using `M-x add-dir-local-variable`.
- Set the `TeX-master` via `dir-locals-set-class-variables`
  and `dir-locals-set-directory-class`.
- Do you all by hand, old-school style:

  ```
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (when (string-prefix-p "/thing/with/colleagues"
                                     default-directory)
                (setq TeX-master "../document"))))
  ```

Comment: I didn't know about this `latex-mode` feature. Unfortunately, it seems that AUCTeX doesn't have it. Thanks for the first two suggestions with `.dir-local.s.el` and `dir-locals-set-{class-variables,directory-class}`, I haven't use them yet, but I'll look them up.

Comment: To set up a `.dir-locals.el` file, the best way is through [Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33064091/957997) using `M-x add-dir-local-variable`. I tried to add the absolute path `((latex-mode (TeX-master (concat default-directory "document"))))`, but I still haven't managed to get it working. When I `eval`, it outputs `t`, which is the AUCTeX output when the open file is the master file. By the way, is there a difference between `.dir-local.s.el` and `.dir-locals.el`?

Comment: @Yamaneko: w.r.t to `.dir-local.s.el` and `.dir-locals.el`, yes there's a big difference: the first doesn't work (was a typo, thanks!).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure. This answer is exactly what I need. As soon as I get it working, I'll accept it. Let me try a couple times more and I'll report later.

Comment: @Yamaneko: Also, feel free to improve the answer with a description of how to use `add-dir-local-variable`.